# При выделении нескольких строк в listbox как их занести в массив или коллекцию?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Есть listbox в котором пользователь будет выбирать несколько строк. Как их занести в коллекцию или массив при нажатии на кнопку "Сохранить" ?

Comment: WinForms  исправил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возьмите свойство

listBox.SelectedItems

Это и есть готовая коллекция.

```
string[] items = new string[listBox.SelectedItems.Count];
listBox.SelectedItems.CopyTo(items,0);
List<string> tb3 = new List<string>(items);
```

Comment: Как мне ее присвоить к обычной коллекции ? Например private static List<string> tb3 = new List<string>();

Comment: как-то так, думаю

Comment: Большое спасибо!!

Comment: Так получается два копирования.

Comment: чтобы понятнее было